# nw.js freeze after a long time in background

Tags: javascript, server, nw.js

I have a little problem with nw.js. I've "googlised" for many days (weeks) but I can't find any solution.
So, I use nw.js as client to connect to an internal server.
It work like a classic web site. We can access to this site with the IP address (192.168. etc...) with a web browser or with my nw.js app.
With any browser on any computer, it work perfectly but with nw.js, when the application stay in background for a long time (a least 1 or 2 hours) the application seems to freeze for few minutes as we click on it to bring it in the foreground.
The window and the page are appearing but nothing respond.
It look like nw.js restart ine background.
After a couple of minutes, everything work again.
I've tried to send a request to the server every 5 minutes so nw.js would stay alive buy it didn't worked.
I have the same result with nw.js in 2 different company (2 different building, 2 servers, no links between companies).

Does anyone have met this kind of freeze?

**Edit**

I think I have something new.

After a time, the memory usage of the 4 nw.js processes is extremely reduced. From about 80 Mo to 4 Mo for example. the problem come at this moment.
I think it's linked with the Automatic Tab Discarding.
maybe if I put `"chromium-args": "--memory-pressure-off"` in the file "package.json".
I'm not sure about this chromium flag.

Answer (score 1):

So I was right. 
Since I added the following flag to the "package.json", everything work perfectly.

```
"chromium-args": "--memory-pressure-off"
```

Maybe it can help someone.